# EF Code First creating useless columns in my database. Why?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I have something like this:

```
public class Account
    {
        [Key]
        public Guid AccountId { get; set; }
    }

    public class TransactionHistory
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public Account Sender { get; set; }
        public Account Receiver { get; set; }
    }
```

My modelbuilder looks like this:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<TransactionHistory>()
                .HasRequired(history => history.Sender)
                .WithMany()
                .Map(s => s.MapKey("Sender"))
                .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

            modelBuilder.Entity<TransactionHistory>()
                .HasRequired(history => history.Receiver)
                .WithMany()
                .Map(s => s.MapKey("Receiver"))
                .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
```

And in my database, my TransactionHistory table got three columns: sender, receiver, and Account_AccountId. While first two columns are ok, i don't want that third column and i don't know why CodeFirst created it... Can you help me with this?

Comment: Do you have a collection property - like `ICollection<TransactionHistory>` - in your `Account` class?

Comment: Yes i do, but only one collection. (previously i had two just to avoid this error, i mapped sender and receiver to each of those)

Comment: @Slauma, Oh well. I am dumb, i don't know how i wanted this to work. Removed that single collection in `Account` class and it works. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A collection like `ICollection<TransactionHistory>` in `Account` will lead to a third relationship with its own foreign key in `Account`. That's the additional key you are seeing. If you don't want a third relationship you must decide which navigation property in `Account` you want to relate the collection to. Either...

```
modelBuilder.Entity<TransactionHistory>()
            .HasRequired(history => history.Sender)
            .WithMany(account => account.TransactionHistories)
            .Map(s => s.MapKey("Sender"))
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
```

...or...

```
modelBuilder.Entity<TransactionHistory>()
            .HasRequired(history => history.Receiver)
            .WithMany(account => account.TransactionHistories)
            .Map(s => s.MapKey("Receiver"))
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
```

But not both. Or alternatively remove the collection property and the third FK will disappear.

Comment: It works, but now i got another error, when i try to `context.Transactions.Add(history);`, i got exception that says `Entities in 'Db.Transactions' participate in the 'TransactionHistory_Sender' relationship. '0' related 'TransactionHistory_Sender_Target' were found. Between TransactionHistory_Sender_Target '1' are expected.` What does it mean O.o

Comment: @ojek: It probably means that `history.Sender` is `null`, is it?

Comment: Yes. It is. But it is supposed to be that way. I want to put there Account, but i want to not put anything in there too. How do i do that?

Comment: .HasRequired must go into .HasOptional. Thanks! :)

Comment: @ojek: I just was going to write that :)

Answer (score 0):

I think doing this will fix it.

```
[Column("ID")]
[Key]
public int Id { get; set; }
```

Also I would consider changing your mappings to `s.MapKey("SenderAccountID")` and `s.MapKey("ReceiverAccountID")`.  Makes life easier for people working in your DB.

Comment: But i don't want to change my key property, EF just adds another columnt that i don't want there.